# How to move a character diagonally using the keyboard in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

My character can only move horizontally and vertically. I want the program to catch two keystrokes at the same time, not just one.
I use WinForms.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        Player.Move(Direction.Left);
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        Player.Move(Direction.Right);
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        Player.Move(Direction.Up);
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        Player.Move(Direction.Down);
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @RezaAghaei I don't think that will work for "extra" keys besides modifier keys.  But you could certainly keep track of which keys are down by tracking KeyUps as well as KeyDowns.

Comment: @adv12 Oops, my mistake. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the key states using [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
public const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x8000;
public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState((int)key) & KEY_PRESSED);
}
```

When you check the key state using `IsKeyDown(Keys.A)` the method returns `true` if the key is pressed at the moment of checking the state.

Then in each key down event, you can check the key state for <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>. You can map those keys to positions in a binary number and calculate the valid combinations based on the following table:

```
|S|D|W|A| Number | Direction | 
------------------------------
|0|0|0|1| 1      | ←         |
|0|0|1|0| 2      | ↑         |
|0|0|1|1| 3      | ↖         |
|0|1|0|0| 4      | →         |
|0|1|1|0| 6      | ↗         |
|1|0|0|0| 8      | ↓         |
|1|0|0|1| 9      | ↙         |
|1|1|0|0| 12     | ↘         |
```

**Example**

The following example assume there's a label on a form and we want to move the label with <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> keys:

[image]

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
public const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x8000;
public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState((int)key) & KEY_PRESSED);
}
```

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var keyStates = new System.Collections.BitArray(new bool[]{
        IsKeyDown(Keys.A), IsKeyDown(Keys.W),
        IsKeyDown(Keys.D), IsKeyDown(Keys.S)});
    var combination = new byte[1];
    keyStates.CopyTo(combination, 0);

    var c = label1; var d = 3;

    switch (combination[0])
    {
        case 1:
            c.Text = "←"; c.Left -= d; break;
        case 2:
            c.Text = "↑"; c.Top -= d; break;
        case 3:
            c.Text = "↖"; c.Left -= d; c.Top -= d; break;
        case 4:
            c.Text = "→"; c.Left += d; break;
        case 6:
            c.Text = "↗"; c.Left += d; c.Top -= d; break;
        case 8:
            c.Text = "↓"; c.Top += d; break;
        case 9:
            c.Text = "↙"; c.Left -= d; c.Top += d; break;
        case 12:
            c.Text = "↘"; c.Left += d; c.Top += d; break;
        default:
            c.Text = ""; break;
    }
    Invalidate();
}
```